# SaltStack state to install .deb package file and dependencies

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, salt-stack, deb

I have a salt formula. On server I am using `wkhtmltopdf` tools. Ubuntu repo has this tool but it has an older version. I want to use the latest version.

I am doing the following to get it installed on minions manually.

```
$ wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install fontconfig libfontenc1 libjpeg-turbo8 libxfont1 x11-common xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils libxrender1
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

I can do `cmd.run` for all these commands. Is there any better way of doing any of these steps?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify a remote `sources` option in a Salt pkg state. You could try something like this

```
cat stuff.sls

my_pkgs:
  - pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - fontconfig
      - libfontenc1
      - libjpeg-turbo8 
      - libxfont1
      - x11-common
      - xfonts-75dpi
      - xfonts-base
      - xfonts-encodings
      - xfonts-utils
      - libxrender1

install_wkhtmltox:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - wkhtmltox: http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank's that worked, I actually copied deb file in salt files and referred as source, that way not have to rely on the availability of the download url.

Comment: Great idea! I was going to suggest downloading that deb to your master, but wasn't sure if that was acceptable

Comment: I'm using this to download and install https://vivaldi.com/download/vivaldi_TP4.1.0.219.50-1_amd64.deb.  The URL works fine in Firefox, but Salt gives me MinionError: HTTP error 403 reading https://vivaldi.com/download/vivaldi_TP4.1.0.219.50-1_amd64.deb: Request forbidden -- authorization will not help
  Any ideas?